# cucumber (in Java): How can I run scenarios with both tags only

Tags: java, tags, cucumber, scenarios

I have some feature files with multiple tags for each scenario. But I would like to run those who has both @a AND @b scenarios. How can I do that?

```
    tags = {"@a, @b"},  --> this will do @a OR @b scenarios
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out:
tags = {"@a, @b"},  --> this will do @a OR @b scenarios
**tags = {"@a", "@b"},  --> this will do @a AND @b scenarios**